# IE9 Shrinks image in Nivo Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nivo-slider

I'm using Nivo slider and Fancy box together and I'm getting this problem that I cannot seem to correct.

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JaHe/3uC8s/) to try and replicate the problem I'm having.

```
    .nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:auto 265px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    max-width: none;
    display: none;
}
```

If you look very closely, you can see that the image are slightly shrinking and expanding, that the problem I'm having but you can see it, but its on a larger scale.

I have my suspicions that its something to do with the positioning in the CSS after looking here on SO but I've commented out the positioning tag in a few places and nothing has made a difference. Apparently IE9 doesn't count the auto CSS tag for height or width, this may be a problem, I have removed every auto tag, but that still hasn't made a difference.

Like I say it works fine across every browser including IE10 and IE11.

Also my version of jQuery is 2.1.1 could this be a problem

Comment: Have you got a DTD? Which are you using?

Comment: Hi @BigChris, yes i have this is the one <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: Try a strict DTD as per the W3C recommendation: http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: hi, i've just tried a few and the problem is still persisting

Comment: Try the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872634/nivo-slider-first-image-is-scaled-unproportional-when-displayed-the-first-time - worked in your JSFiddle with IE9 browser mode.

Comment: Nice one @BigChris that seems to have done the trick, cheers.